# PostgresSQL: Validate specific value exists once in the column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, unique

I'm trying to check the uniqueness where for the same values in the column **APP** will exist only specific value in the column **STATUS**.

Example:
Each app can be only once "true".
APP cannot be a PRIMARY KEY.
The DB should restrict adding additional row with *(app1, true)* and permit *(app1, false)*

| ID | APP | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | app1 | false |
| 2 | app1 | **true** |
| 3 | app1 | false |
| 4 | app2 | false |
| 5 | app2 | false |
| 6 | app2 | false |
| 7 | app2 | **true** |

Maybe constraint, or indexing can help here?

Comment: You can't do it with a `CHECK` constraint clause. The only thing you could do is implementing a trigger that checks the presence of "*true*" for the specific app during the insertion operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @lemon suggestion in comments you could use a trigger or as an alternative:

```
create table unique_test (
   id integer, 
   app varchar, 
   status boolean, 
   unique(app, status));

insert into unique_test values (1, 'app1', null);
insert into unique_test values (2, 'app2', null);
insert into unique_test values (3, 'app1', 'true');
insert into unique_test values (4, 'app1',  null);

insert into unique_test values (5, 'app1',  'true');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
"unique_test_app_status_key"
DETAIL:  Key (app, status)=(app1, t) already exists.

insert into unique_test values (5, 'app1',  null);
insert into unique_test values (6, 'app2',  'true');

select * from unique_test ;
 id | app  | status 
----+------+--------
  1 | app1 | NULL
  2 | app2 | NULL
  3 | app1 | t
  4 | app1 | NULL
  5 | app1 | NULL
  6 | app2 | t
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `UNIQUE` sees `NULL`'s as unique from each other. FYI in the upcoming Postgres 15 this behavior can be modified so that is not so, see [Unique and NULLS](https://blog.rustprooflabs.com/2022/07/postgres-15-unique-improvement-with-null).

Comment: I need the only one true and other should be false. 

```
 id | app  | status 
----+------+--------
  1 | app1 | NULL
  2 | app2 | NULL
  3 | app1 | t
  4 | app1 | NULL
  5 | app1 | NULL
  6 | app2 | t

```
Maybe I have to implement it programmatically,  and perform validations by code?
Thanks

Comment: Really you just want one app row with  `true`  and the rest not `true`.

Comment: Actually use NULLs and true is a great idea!
I've added now CHECK (status IS NOT FALSE) and now only NULLs or single TRUE can exists at the same time.

Thanks a lot @lemon and @Adrian!